# implement a runner that iterates over an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

**BOLD** denotes updates.

I have an array, `steps`, whose contents are objects with an action and element associated with them. Like so:

```
steps = [{action: 'click', element: <jQuery element>}, 
         {action: 'click', element: <jQuery element>}, ., ., N]
```

I would like to implement a runner, whose job is to run through each element in the array and perform the particular action upon the element. Each step must be performed in serial. So for example, if you have:

```
 steps = [{action: 'click', element: <jQuery element representing a button>},
          {action: 'click', element: <jQuery element representing an anchor tag>}]
```

Running, `run(steps, timeout)`, would run through each step. step[0].action would be performed on step[0].element. Since it is possible for step[0] to create the dom element (**by means of AJAX**) to be interacted with in step[1], the runner needs to wait a particular period(hence, the timeout), polling the dom for the presence of step[1].element.

Here is a rough take at what I have so far:

```
var run = function() { 
    $.each(steps, function(i, v) { 
        var interval = 25, 
            start = 0, 
            timeout = 3000; 
        var i = setInterval(function(timeout) { 
            start = start + interval; 
            console.log(start); 
            if ($(v).is(':visible')) { 
                v.click(); 
                console.log('clicked', v); 
                clearInterval(i);
            }   
        }, interval);
    }); 
};
```

Note that in the above example, `steps` is just an array of jquery objects. It isn't in the desired format just yet:

```
steps = [{action: 'click', element: <jQuery element>}, 
         {action: 'click', element: <jQuery element>}, ., ., N]
```

What is the 'pattern' so to say, that I need to follow? Do I need to use deferred objects to take care of this? Is it implemented with a setTimeout, setInterval? Thanks!

**Final implementation**

```
var run = function(steps, interval, timeout) {
    var timer,
        time = 0,
        i = 0;

    runSingle(steps[0]);

    function abort() {
        console.log("Run aborted");
    }

    function runSingle(step) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            time += interval;
            if ($(step.element).is(':visible') === true) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                time = 0;
                $(step.element).trigger(step.action);
                (i < (steps.length - 1)) && runSingle(steps[++i]);
            } else if (time >= timeout) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                abort();
            }
        }, interval);
        console.log("Performed: ", step.action, "on", step.element) 
        if (i === (steps.length - 1)) console.log("Run successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `<jQuery element>` represent a jQuery object, or just a CSS selector to be used as a jQuery selector? If it's already a jQuery object, it won't update when new elements are added to the DOM...

Comment: Thanks. Currently it is a jqueryobject I will have to update that to use a selector.

Comment: If your selector is a class selector, and there are other elements already on the page with that class, how would you know whether the previous function has done its job already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something. I haven't tested it thoroughly:

```
var run = function(steps, interval)
{
    var timer,
        time = 0, timeout = 10000,
        ciel = steps.length - 1,
        i = 0;

    run_single(steps[0]);

    function run_single(item)
    {
        timer = setInterval(function()
        {
            var $el = $(item.selector);

            time += interval;

            if ( $el.length )
            {
                clearInterval( timer );
                time = 0;

                $el.trigger( item.action );

                i < ciel && run_single( step[ ++i ] );
            }
            else
            {
                if ( time >= timeout ) clearInterval( timer );
            }

        }, interval);
    }
};

var steps = [
    {action: 'click', selector: '#first'},
    {action: 'hover', selector: '#second'},
    {action: 'change', selector: '#third'}
    // and so on...
];

run(steps, 100);
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/myaeh/

Comment: @kennethkoontz - I updated the code a bit (I had some omissions in there), and included a fiddle. Hope it works for you...

Comment: Thanks! I used your implementation to solve the problem. I've updated the post to show what I did.

Answer (score 1):

First up, note that in your example the `v` variable will represent an object from your array and thus it doesn't make sense to say `v.click()` or `$(v).is(':visible')` - you'd want to say `v.element.click()` or `v.element.is(':visible')`.

If you mean that `action` will be a string that is the name of a jQuery method, and `element` is a jQuery object, then you can do something like this:

```
$.each(steps, function(i, obj) { 
    obj.element[obj.action]();
});
```

If `element` is a string representing a selector that should be used to create a jQuery object then:

```
$.each(steps, function(i, obj) { 
    $(obj.element)[obj.action]();
});
```

You don't need to introduce the polling concept unless the `action` might do something asynchronously, for example, if it does a fade-in, or adds elements via Ajax.

In your example the only criterion you seem to be applying for whether to proceed with the current step is whether the current element is visible. If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
var run = function(steps, delay, timeout) {
             var i = 0,
                 nextStep = function() {
                    if (i < steps.length) {
                       var step = steps[i],
                           retryDelay = 25,
                           retryTotal = 0,
                           intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                              retryTotal += retryDelay;
                              var $el = $(step.element);
                              if ($el.is(':visible')) { 
                                $el[step.action](); 
                                clearInterval(intervalId);
                                i++;
                                setTimeout(nextStep, delay);
                              } else if (retryTotal >= timeout) {
                                clearInterval(intervalId);
                              }
                           }, retryDelay);
                    };
                 }
             nextStep();
};

run(steps, 50, 3000);
```

The `run()` function defines a `nextStep()` function that uses `setInterval` to keep checking whether the current element is visible. Once it is, it performs the action, clears the interval, and moves on to the next element by calling itself via `setTimeout`.

I wasn't sure how to fit the timeout concept in with the polling, because if the current element isn't visible after the specified amount of time what would you do? You can't really continue on to the next element because it too might depend on previous steps. I guess you could just abort the whole thing by clearing the interval and *not* calling `nextStep()` again. **EDIT:** I've updated the code to work as per that last sentence.

Comment: Sorry. I should have made it more clear that performing a click on any of the elements, could create a dom element by means of ajax. I'll update the post.

Comment: Also, to clarify this concern, "if the current element isn't visible after the specified amount of time what would you do?", the runner would abort.

Comment: OK, I've made a little update to the code to abort the whole thing if any given step times out. Also I've changed it to assume that the `element` property of each step is a jQuery _selector_, not a jQuery _object_, so that you can specify selectors for elements created by ajax in previous steps.

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer as it is technically correct, but I used a different implementation. Thanks for your answer!